# Setting border radius of first and last child to zero?

Tags: html, css

I have a [project test page here](https://superflycss.github.io/component-button/target/test/html/bootstrap/) and for test 23 (u-button-group) I'm trying to set the border radius of the first and last items in `u-button-group` (There are only 2) to `0px`, and right now it's not working.  This is the css for the `u-button-group` and I'll include  screenshot as well:

```
  .u-button-group {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .u-button-group: first-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 0px !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px !important;
  }

  .u-button-group: last-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 0px !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px !important;
  }
```

[image]

The source code for the `u-button-group` utilities can also be [found here](https://github.com/superflycss/component-button/blob/master/src/main/css/utilities.css).  Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, exactly - but you can do something like u-button-group *:first-child if you want to be more general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `.u-button-group button:first-child {...}`

The term "child" is maybe a bit misleading. As it describes a property of a button in the above example, it references on the first button. If you use it on .u-button-group it would mean the first of those groups.

Comment: Awesome - GOT IT!!  Thanks!  I ended up using the * option, so thanks for pointing that out as well!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this.

`.u-button-group .bs-Button--primary:first-child`

In your example, you are not specific enough to select the button. The child in your example is referring to the `u-button-group` not the button itself.

Here's what the [MDN specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) are saying.

> The :first-child CSS pseudo-class represents the first element among a group of sibling elements.

Here's a working example that selects the buttons instead.

```css
.u-button-group {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.u-button-group .bs-Button--primary {
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.u-button-group .bs-Button--primary:first-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 0px !important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px !important;
}

.u-button-group .bs-Button--primary:last-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 0px !important;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="TestRender">
  <div class="u-button-group">
    <button class="bs-Button--primary">first block button</button>
    <button class="bs-Button--primary">lastblock button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Close - I had to use the *:first-child selector because it needs to work for any button class or different button like elements (a, input, etc).